# how to create a table by using Nattable and add value into its column

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have to create a Nat Table with three column and add value in the column.please help me. thanks in Advance

Comment: Read the documentation and tutorials we created http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html

Comment: i read this article but i did not get a clear idea regarding nat table.Will u please show me a example through which i can easily understand

Comment: I wonder if you really read the article. It tells about the NatTable Example Application, which contains multiple examples to understand. And the article itself contains several tutorials for a better understanding. If all that information does not help to get a better understanding, either try to buy some consulting or training or use another widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps. For the details of the layer you can refer the http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html link which is quite apt.

```
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.NatTable;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.AbstractRegistryConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.CellConfigAttributes;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.ConfigRegistry;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.IConfigRegistry;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.data.IDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DefaultCornerDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DummyBodyDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.ColumnHeaderLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.CornerLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.GridLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.RowHeaderLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.hideshow.ColumnHideShowLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractLayerTransform;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.DataLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.LabelStack;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.cell.IConfigLabelAccumulator;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.reorder.ColumnReorderLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.selection.SelectionLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.CellStyleAttributes;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.DisplayMode;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.Style;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.util.GUIHelper;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.viewport.ViewportLayer;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class Nat_explore {

private BodyLayerStack bodyLayer ;
private int statusColumn;
private int statusRejected;
private int statusInProgress;
private boolean check = false;
private NatTable nattable;
private String[] properties;
private static final String FOO_LABEL = "FOO";
private static final String CELL_LABEL = "Cell_LABEL";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Nat_explore();
}

public Nat_explore() {

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());      

                properties = new String[3];

                for(int i=0;i<properties.length;i++){

                    properties[i]="Column"+i;   
                }

                //Setting the data layout layer
                GridData gridData = new GridData();
                gridData.heightHint = (int) 24;
                gridData.widthHint = (int) 110;

                IConfigRegistry configRegistry = new ConfigRegistry();

                //Body Data Provider
                IDataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(properties.length,55);
                bodyLayer= new BodyLayerStack(dataProvider);
                //datalayer.addConfiguration(new 

                //Column Data Provider
                DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider columnData = new DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider(properties);
                ColumnHeaderLayerStack columnlayer = new ColumnHeaderLayerStack(columnData);

                //Row Data Provider
                DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider rowdata = new DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider(dataProvider);
                RowHeaderLayerStack rowlayer = new RowHeaderLayerStack(rowdata);

                //Corner Data Provider
                DefaultCornerDataProvider cornerdata = new DefaultCornerDataProvider(columnData, rowdata);
                DataLayer cornerDataLayer = new DataLayer(cornerdata);
                CornerLayer cornerLayer = new CornerLayer(cornerDataLayer, rowlayer, columnlayer);

                GridLayer gridlayer = new GridLayer(bodyLayer, columnlayer, rowlayer, cornerLayer);
                nattable = new NatTable(shell, gridlayer,false);

                // Change for paint
                IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
                    //@Override
                    public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels,int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {

                        int columnIndex = bodyLayer.getColumnIndexByPosition(columnPosition);
                        int rowIndex = bodyLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);
                        if (columnIndex == 2 && rowIndex == 45) {
                            configLabels.addLabel(FOO_LABEL);
                        }
                        else if ((columnIndex == statusColumn) && (rowIndex == statusRejected) && (check ==true)) {
                                configLabels.addLabel(CELL_LABEL);
                        }
                    }
                };
                bodyLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);

                nattable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());
                nattable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
                    //@Override
                    public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
                        Style cellStyle = new Style();
                        cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR,GUIHelper.COLOR_YELLOW);
                        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle,DisplayMode.NORMAL, FOO_LABEL);

                        cellStyle = new Style();
                        cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR,GUIHelper.COLOR_RED);
                        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle,DisplayMode.NORMAL, CELL_LABEL);
                    }
                });

                nattable.setLayoutData(gridData);
                nattable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
                nattable.configure();

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if(!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();

}

public class DataProvider extends DummyBodyDataProvider{

    public DataProvider(int columnCount, int rowCount) {
        super(columnCount, rowCount);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return properties.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDataValue(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {

        return new String("Column"+columnIndex+" Row"+rowIndex);

    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 55;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataValue(int arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {

    }
}

public class BodyLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {

    private SelectionLayer selectionLayer;

    public BodyLayerStack(IDataProvider dataProvider) {
        DataLayer bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider);
        ColumnReorderLayer columnReorderLayer = new ColumnReorderLayer(bodyDataLayer);
        ColumnHideShowLayer columnHideShowLayer = new ColumnHideShowLayer(columnReorderLayer);
        this.selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(columnHideShowLayer);
        ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(this.selectionLayer);
        setUnderlyingLayer(viewportLayer);
    }

    public SelectionLayer getSelectionLayer() {
        return this.selectionLayer;
    }
}

public class ColumnHeaderLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {

    public ColumnHeaderLayerStack(IDataProvider dataProvider) {
        DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider);
        ColumnHeaderLayer colHeaderLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayer(dataLayer,Nat_explore.this.bodyLayer, Nat_explore.this.bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());
        setUnderlyingLayer(colHeaderLayer);
    }
}

public class RowHeaderLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {

    public RowHeaderLayerStack(IDataProvider dataProvider) {
        DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider, 50, 20);
        RowHeaderLayer rowHeaderLayer = new RowHeaderLayer(dataLayer,Nat_explore.this.bodyLayer, Nat_explore.this.bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());setUnderlyingLayer(rowHeaderLayer);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If this has solved your question we can close the question.